# Wording on average

Tags: probability, soft-question

This is a soft question

> What we [on average] mean when we say "customers/patients visit a hospital $1$ to $3$ times a year on **average**"?

Does this mean, that the probability to visit $1$, $2$ or $3$ times is exactly $\frac{1}{3}$ ? [discrete uniform]

[image]

Or does it mean, that each customer has its own distribution $X_k$, with $\mathbb{E}(X_k) \in [1,3]$ being the only requirement?

[image]

Comment: For each customer you count the number of visits per year. Then you take the average of these numbers. Done.

Comment: Yes [was it the question?]. But, it is deeply different if a customer should at least visit once, or s/he could do it 99 times but with a negligible probability

Comment: @Wuestenfux, then we would say on average it is 2.34, but not from 1 to 3 ...

Comment: The average might mean the mode. The frequency distribution of visits might be tr--modal with significant peaks at 1, 2 and 3 visits and little elsewhere. The "mean" is probably not a useful measure of average here.

Answer (score 1):

When you reduce the question to 'on average $3$ times per year' it becomes clearer. Now the average number of visit equals $3$. Still every visitor has his own number of visits and therefore also his own distribution with $E = 3$.

Saying on average $1$ to $3$ simply gives a range for the expectation but doesn't change the distripution.

In conclusion, statement number 2 is correct.